# jQuery position() returns zero values if element positioning is set to absolute

Tags: jquery, position, css-position, zero

I have some divs with class "area", floated next to each other. I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(".area").each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(this).css({"left":pos.left, "top":pos.top});
});
```

This works fine, but alas, top and left are not taken into consideration by the browser when the element is positioned statically. If I modify the position value for the elements, pos.left and pos.top are both zero. That is, if I have this code:

```
$(".area").each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(this).css({"left":pos.left, "top":pos.top, "position":"absolute"});
});
```

then `$(this).position()` consistently returns `{left:0,top:0}`. Do I misunderstand how `$.position()` works, of do I misunderstand how CSS position works, or is this a bug? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried offset instead? Have you set parent to position relative?

Comment: It may be helpful to see a jsFiddle but a theory could be: The first element is at top:0,left:0, and second element is at (hypothetically) top:0,left:20. On the first iteration it sets element1 to absolute, removing it from the flow and causing element2 to reposition to 0,0. Thus you always get 0,0 because each element is taken out of flow one by one and moving the next element to the initial starting position.

Comment: Parent position is set to relative, yes. I did not try offset, because position() is the function for my needs. Infact, it is working, so long as position: absolute is not set on an element. As I am iterating through the elements, position() return zero values BEFORE being positioned absolutely. If position is not set to absolute, all is fine. If at some point inside the callback I set the css position of the currently processed element, it's position value becomes (0,0) even though it is the very first statement... :/

Comment: Check my answer and see if that helps. If not, post a jsFiddle and I can understand the problem better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up to my comment. I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tTJmf/) example explaining what's happening.

When you position your first `.area` it removes it from the flow and now your second `.area` takes its position. This continues for each iteration in the `$.each()`. So if your first element starts at position 0,0 then when it's moved to absolute the next element becomes 0,0. Ideally you would need to save an array with your positions first then re-position them:

```
$(".area").each(function () {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    savedPos.push({
        left: pos.left,
        top: pos.top
    });
});
$(".area").each(function (i) {
    $(this).css({
        "position": 'absolute',
        "left": savedPos[i].left,
        "top": savedPos[i].top
    });
});
```

Or set position after you set left/right:

```
$(".area").each(function () {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(this).css({
        "left":pos.left,
        "top": pos.top
    });
});
$('.area').css('position','absolute');
```